# float divs next to each other in absolutely aligned container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align a few buttons in a DIV popup I created. I want the buttons to be next to each other, but I cannot seem to make it work. I tried adding, float: left, but it does not seem to have an effect. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

```
    <div id="pop_box">Hello there sir!
    <div class="pop_buttons">Update Quantity</div> 
    <div class="pop_buttons">Check Out</div> 
    <div class="pop_buttons">Close Cart</div>
    </div>
```

The CSS is as follows:

```
div.pop_box
{
z-index:3;
width:70%;
height:70%;
bottom:20%;
right:15%;
overflow:auto;
background-color:#434343;
position:absolute;
border-color:#808080;
border-style:solid;
border-collapse:collapse;
border-width:1px;
padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

div.pop_buttons 
{
z-index: 4;
margin: 10px;
width: 100px;
height: 20px;
line-height:20px;
text-align:center;
bottom: 30%;
right: 30%;
font-family: 'Segoe UI', Arial;
font-size: 12px;
vertical-align:middle;
background-color:#808080;
}
```

UPDATE: Keep in mind that the buttons are contained in container "pop_box"...This makes a big difference, because pop_box has position:absolute.

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/35R3J/

Comment: Besides, `z-index: 4;` is unnecessary since z-index only affects positioned elements.

Comment: put on your buttons display: inline-block;

Comment: Agree with the @KevinBoucher, did you actually add the float: left in? I don't see it in your example code.

Comment: Note: float:left was missing in OP CSS; plus, it contains a bunch of unrelated properties. The "clean" version is included in my answer. Rgds,

Comment: The properties do not need to be cleaned up, this is clearly not the whole website here, z-index is required due to some overlap issues. And yes, I have tried adding float:left already, as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS selector is incorrect, it should be `div#pop_box` and **not** `div.pop_box`. You're also missing the `float:left` for `div.pop_buttons` in your question. Otherwise, it should all work as you expect.

#### Demo: http://jsbin.com/ulukid

Comment: Strange, it is not working for me, the syntax is fine because I use jQuery to add the class:         $('#pop_box').addClass('pop_box');

Comment: Regardless, adjusting the HTML to add a class manually for examples sake and reverting the CSS selector, the floats still float. http://jsbin.com/ulukid/2

Comment: The problem is, I have another class ".hidden" affecting id=pop_box, oClick using jQuery I change the class to "pop_box."

Comment: Ok, it works, the browser cache needed to be cleared, browser issue :)

Answer (score 2):

When you wrap the buttons in another `div` and add `float: left` to `pop_buttons`, you get them nicely lined up

```
<div id="pop_box">Hello there sir!
    <div>
        <div class="pop_buttons">Update Quantity</div>
        <div class="pop_buttons">Check Out</div>
        <div class="pop_buttons">Close Cart</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.pop_buttons {
    z-index: 4;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height:20px;
    text-align:center;
    bottom: 30%;
    right: 30%;
    font-family:'Segoe UI', Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background-color:#808080;
    float: left;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ehYsZ/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following (**see demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/Z9vCb/):

**HTML**

```
<div id="pop_box">Hello there Sir!
     <br/>
    <div class="pop_buttons">Update Quantity</div> 
    <div class="pop_buttons">Check Out</div> 
    <div class="pop_buttons">Close Cart</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.pop_box {
position:absolute;
z-index:3;
background-color:#434343;
border-color:#808080;
border-style:solid;
padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

div.pop_buttons {
float:left;
position:relative;
margin-right: 10px;
width: 100px;
height: 20px;
line-height:20px;
text-align:center;
font-family: 'Segoe UI', Arial;
font-size: 12px;
background-color:#808080;
}
```

Note: this is a "cleaned-up" CSS version, because your original one contains plenty of irrelevant properties, which is seemingly not applicable in this case.